# UITableView reloadData not working without rows

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

The situation:

For a UITableView, I am using a filter textview.
This tableview contains countries over the world. When the search value length is >= 4, a smart search should start. This smart search uses the iOS CLGeocoder, so you can also use synonyms or capital cities to find a country.

My problem:

Everytime the text changes, the uitableview's methods 'reloadData' is called.
When I set a breakpoint on the textChange method and the numberOfRowsInSection method of the uitableview, they are both hit.
But when I want to type London, the normal (not smart) search doesn't have any results at 'Lon'. When I enter the fourth letter (resulting in 'Lond'), the textChange breakpoint is hit, but the numberOfRowsInSection breakpoint is not.

Is it possible that reloadData doesn't update the tableview when the previous reloadData resulted in no rows or something? I have no clue what the exact problem is, anyone who recognizes this situation?

The code:

```
-(void) searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {
    filterText = searchText;

    //smart search
    if([searchText length] >= 4) {
        [self smartSearch:searchText];
    }

    [_contentTableView reloadData];
}

-(void) smartSearch:(NSString*) text {
    CLGeocoder* gc = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];

    [gc geocodeAddressString:text completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error)
     {
         smartSearchResult = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
         for(CLPlacemark *mark in placemarks) {
             [smartSearchResult addObject:mark.country];
             NSLog(@"Smart search result: %@", mark.country);
         }

         [_contentTableView reloadData];
    }];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    NSPredicate *predicate = [self createFilterPredicate];
    NSArray *filtered = [countries filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

    return filtered.count;
}
```

The method createFilterPredicate creates a predicate, but that method works so I didn't include it here.

Comment: Can you add some code you are using???

Comment: Adding your code will make sense.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.

Comment: Sorry guys, I thought this was just basic UITableView code so I didn't add it. Now I did!

Comment: @harmjanr Do you know that `geocodeAddressString:completionHandler:` executes a web call? Are you sure you're waiting for that asynchronous block to return?

Comment: @mbm29414 Yeah, that's why I do a reloadData in de completionhandler as well..

Comment: @harmjanr It looks like you might be creating an array (`smartSearchResult`) that's never used? I don't see where you use the generated array (though without your interface declaration, I don't know for sure. Is your `numberOfSections...` returning zero? If so, it won't go on to ask for `numberOfRows...`.

Comment: @mbm29414 The array smartSearchResult is used in the method createFilterPredicate. Your other point about the numberOfSections makes sense, it looks like this returns 0. I'll get into this and let you know!

Comment: @mbm29414 That was the problem, awesome! Add it as an answer so I can accept it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating an array (`smartSearchResult`) that's never used. You should have a property declaration to store the items so that you can access it in your `UITableViewDataSource` methods. Otherwise, the data you're gathering in `geocodeAddressString:completionHandler:` will be lost and you'll still be returning 0 from `numberOfSectionsInTableView:`.

Something **like** this should do the trick (I'm having to make some guesses on the rest of your class structure):

```
@interface TableViewController : UITableViewController {

}
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray   *dataSource;
@property (copy  , nonatomic) NSString  *filterText;
@end
@implementation TableViewController
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark - UITableViewDataSource Protocol Methods
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    if (self.dataSource == nil) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    NSPredicate *predicate = [self createFilterPredicate];
    NSArray *filtered = [countries filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
    return filtered.count;
}
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {
    self.filterText = searchText;
    //smart search
    if (searchText.length > 3) {
        [self smartSearch:searchText];
    }
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
- (void)smartSearch:(NSString *) text {
    CLGeocoder* gc = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
    [gc geocodeAddressString:text completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
         NSMutableArray *smartSearchResult = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
         for (CLPlacemark *mark in placemarks) {
             [smartSearchResult addObject:mark.country];
             NSLog(@"Smart search result: %@", mark.country);
         }
         [self.tableView reloadData];
     }
     ];
}
@end
```